# Predictive Single Nucleotide Polymorphisms (SNPs) for Bipolar Disorder

Tags: psychology, pathophysiology

Are there any validated SNPs that are either predictive of developing bipolar spectrum disorder or are associated with its pathophysiology?

Comment: What do you mean by validated SNP? An association that has been further confirmed?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there have been a variety of studies that do association analysis of variants with bipolar disorder. [Here](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41588-019-0397-8#:%7E:text=Abstract,9%2C412%20cases%20and%20137%2C760%20controls.) is a recent one that validated 11-30 variants depending on how you count.

However, in these kinds of analyses you should be somewhat cautious as the associations are *extremely* weak (as they generally are for complex traits in humans):

> Eight of the 19 variants that were genome-wide significant (P < 5 × 10−8) in the discovery GWAS were not genome-wide significant in the combined analysis, consistent with small effect sizes and limited power but also with genetic heterogeneity.

The statistics of how you interpret such variants are rather dodgy/uncertain, so I would put very little stock in any particular variant. Maybe if you take the genome-wide significant variants only and added them all up you might start to get a little predictive power.

In terms of other more speculative observations (again from the abstract of that study):

> The significant loci contain genes encoding ion channels, neurotransmitter transporters and synaptic components. Pathway analysis revealed nine significantly enriched gene sets, including regulation of insulin secretion and endocannabinoid signaling. Bipolar I disorder is strongly genetically correlated with schizophrenia, driven by psychosis, whereas bipolar II disorder is more strongly correlated with major depressive disorder.

I would suggest reading that paper and finding some further citations from it if you are interested in more detail.